# The Relation Between the Inclusion Relation Between Balls and the Triangle Inequality and How to Distinguish the Certain Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-topology

The setting is as follows. Suppose $(X,\mathrm{d})$ is a metric space. For any $(x,r)\in X\times \mathbb {R}_+$, denote $\mathrm{B}(x,r)$ as the closed ball in $X$, i.e. $\mathrm{B}(x,r)=\{y\in X\left|\ \mathrm{d}(y,x)\le r\right.\}$. We know that **for any $(x_1,r_1)$ and $(x_2,r_2)$ satisfying $\mathrm{d}(x_1,x_2)\le r_2-r_1$, by the triangle inequality, we have $\mathrm{B}(x_1,r_1)\subset \mathrm{B}(x_2,r_2)$. This fact holds for all metric spaces.**

When we think about the converse of this fact, i.e. "For any $(x_1,r_1)$ and $(x_2,r_2)$ satisfying $\mathrm{B}(x_1,r_1)\subset \mathrm{B}(x_2,r_2)$, we have $\mathrm d(x_1,x_2)\le r_2-r_1$." It turns out to be not always true for any metric space $(X,\mathrm{d})$. So the **question** is

**Question.** How can we **give some nice conditions to distinguish the metric spaces** where the property $\mathrm{d}(x_1,x_2)\le r_2-r_1$ and $\mathrm{B}(x_1,r_1)\subset \mathrm{B}(x_2,r_2)$ are equivalent? (Perhaps, you need to change the way we ask this question to make it more reasonable.)

Denote the set of such metric spaces as $\mathcal {E}$. We have known that if $\mathrm{diam}(X)<\infty$, we have $X\notin\mathcal {E}$, since the radius of the ball can be chosen to be larger than the diameter of $X$. Thus, if $X\in\mathcal {E}$, $X$ must be **unbounded**, i.e. $\mathrm{diam}(X)=\infty$.

We have also known that every Euclidean space of finite dimension with the usual metric belongs to $\mathcal {E}$. Every dense subset of a Euclidean space of finite dimension as a metric subspace also belongs to $\mathcal {E}$. For any $n\in\mathbb N=\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$, the upper-half space $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb {R}^{n+1}$, however, doesn't belong to $\mathcal {E}$ (please see the following picture).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ku7e.png)

Hence, we guess if $X\in\mathcal {E}$, $X$ should possess some **completeness** in some sence, just like the Euclidean space of finite dimension.

Moreover, we can prove that every parabola on $\mathbb {R}^2$ doesn't belong to $\mathcal {E}$, since the parabola is pointed or sharp at the extreme point, particularly when we enlarge the parabola (please see the following picture).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTlT2.png)

Meanwhile, we can prove that every sin function on $\mathbb {R}^2$ doesn't belong to $\mathcal {E}$ (please see the following picture (sorry; my vpn doesn't work suddenly)).

https://postimg.cc/9zFPL7T0

Finally, maybe we can prove that every unbounded $C^\infty$ plane curve which is self-intersection point free and not a straight line or a curve with precisely one endpoint doesn't belong to $\mathcal {E}$.

Hence, we also guess if $X\in\mathcal {E}$, $X$ may possess some **flatness** in some sense, just like the Euclidean space of finite dimension. We guess this question may not only be a **point set topology** question, but also need some **differential topology**.

I cannot find any material about this question on the Internet. If you can give me some references or tell me some advanced topics, I will be more than grateful. Thank you for bearing my unreasonable question.

Comment: I think maybe we can suppose that the metric space $X$ is a complete metric space.

Comment: Today, I myself see a new kind of metric spaces that are ultrametric spaces and which don't belong to $\mathcal E$, once you can find a ball that has infinitely many radii in the space. For ultrametric spaces, this kind of oddities aren't rare.

Answer (score 1):

One sufficient condition is:
$\exists (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb N},$ when $n \to +\infty, d(x_1,y_n) \to r_1^-$ (meaning $d(x_1,y_n) \le r_1$ and $d(x_1,y_n) \to r_1$) and $d(x_2, y_n) \to r_1 + d(x_2,x_1)$.
Whether this is a nice condition is subject to appreciation :-)

Proof: suppose we have $B(x_1,r_1) \subset B(x_2,r_2)$ and
$\exists (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb N},$ when $n \to +\infty, d(x_1,y_n) \to r_1^-$ and $d(x_2, y_n) \to r_1 + d(x_2,x_1)$.
Then $d(x_2, y_n) \le r_2$, so
$d(x_2,x_1) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (d(x_2, y_n) - r_1) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} (r_2 - r_1) = r_2-r_1$.

Comment: Thank you. You give a nice condition. It is my opinion that it somehow answers the question from the aspect of "completeness", for example, the half line.